Chrome PWA icons turn blank after pinning on Windows 10 taskbar
UPDATED with new insights

I symlink my Chrome profile to another samba folder for easy backup (been doing so for years)
Recently, that folder was temporarily unavailable and have since been restored
However, a new (mis)behavior started showing up:
My PWA icons are now blank, see attached
It seems that Windows 10 will not load icons that are on the shared samba folder
Currently on Chrome Version 127.0.6533.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), but is happening across a few updates, so I don't think it is an issue with Chrome

Any idea how I can overcome this like before?


Does Microsoft Edge also fail the same way?

I tried with edge, everything works correctly, But I don't use edge and it's profile folder is also not symlinked to another drive's folder

So, it's a Chrome fail - probably fixed in the next release

No it is not, same version of Chrome works correctly on other machines.

that's information you neglected to include in your question :p

did you ask for the version?

No? Did you ask for it?

@bilogic - We should not have to ask what version of Chrome you are using

The issue is happening because Windows won't load icons on remote paths
The keyword to google for is EnableShellShortcutIconRemotePath
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162419/shortcut-icon-blank-when-ico-file-is-located-on-a
I ran this on an administrator command prompt to fix my issue

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /v EnableShellShortcutIconRemotePath /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

